# How to stop this script from moving renamed files out of source folder?

Tags: bash

The script works as far as renaming the files but it moves the renamed files out of their respective folders.

I would like it to not move them but only rename them and I have failed after a few days of trying. I know this code is a mess and there is unneeded code in it but it nearly works.

Also the renamed file isn’t getting an extension of `.txt` but that isn't really an issue for me. I just want to see the "Dynamic Range Value" that is taken from inside the file as the file name so I don’t have to open every file (a couple thousand albums worth) to see what the DR is. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /media/Storage/MusicWorks/Processing
find . -name 'dr14.txt' | while IFS=$'\n' read -r i
do mv -n "$i" `egrep -m1 -e 'Official DR value:' "$i" | sed -e 's/Official DR value://'`;
echo "Done"
done
```

I run this script from the terminal with a bash alias.

Comment: In general, `grep | sed` is [useless](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) and could be better rephrased as just a `sed` script. In your case, it's also dead simple; `sed '/Official DR Value:/!d;s///;q' "$i"`

Comment: @tripleee: Or simpler: `sed -n '/Official DR Value:/{s///p;q;}' "$i"`.  The second semicolon is needed with BSD `sed` but not with GNU `sed`.

Comment: That will print multiple lines if there are several matches in the file. Presumably the `egrep -m1` was added to fix that precise problem.

Comment: @tripleee — Yes; extra fix now incorporated into my previous comment.  I was checking what the `-m1` did when your extra comment arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reservations about the `egrep | sed` part of your script, but if they work for you, so be it.  You need to preserve the pathname of the file, for example like this:

```
find . -name 'dr14.txt' |
while IFS=$'\n' read -r i
do
    newname="${i%/*}"/$(egrep -m1 -e 'Official DR value:' "$i" | sed -e 's/Official DR value://');
    mv -n "$i" "$newname"
    echo "Done $i ($newname)"
done
```

The `${i%/*}` notation removes anything from the last slash to the end of the name in `$i`.  Since all the names from `find` will start with `./`, this is secure enough; it would not work well on absolute names such as `/` and `/unix` (the output would be the empty string, but `/usr/bin/sh` would be fine).

---

Under a little prompting by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925534/how-to-stop-this-script-from-moving-renamed-files-out-of-source-folder/23925885?noredirect=1#comment36849498_23925534), it is possible to simplify the `egrep | sed` part of the code to:

```
    newname="${i%/*}"/$(sed -n -e '/Official DR value:/{s///p;q;}' "$i");
```

The second semicolon is needed with BSD `sed` but not with GNU `sed`.

Comment: Hello Jonathan, Thank you very much for your help on this script. I really appreciate it. The code you posted works without a flaw and will make it much easier to view what the Dynamic Range of an album is without opening the file. Perfect, and thanks again:) Cheers